# How to sum the result of async requests?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have an async function that returns a number (int) to me on each request, how do I add it up and print it correct to the console?

```
async def get_on_sale(session, dictt):
    data = {}
    sale_total_sum = 0
    amount_total_items = 0

    async with session.get(f'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/items?key={dictt[1][1]}') as resp:
        html = await resp.json()
        
        if html['items'] is None:
            pass
        else:
            each_sale_sum = 0
            each_amount_items = 0
            
            for i in html['items']:
                sale_total_sum += i['price']
                each_sale_sum += i['price']
                each_amount_items += 1
                amount_total_items += 1
            
            key = dictt[0]
            value = dictt[1][0]
            data.setdefault(key, [])
            data[key].append(value)
            data[key].append(each_sale_sum)
            data[key].append(each_amount_items)

    for key, value in data.items():
        print(f'Nick: {key} Items each sum: {each_sale_sum}')
    print(f'Total sale sum: {sale_total_sum} Items total: {amount_total_items}')


async def Main():
    profiles = users()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []
        if user_input == 'sell':
            for i in profiles.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_on_sale(session, i))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(Main())
```

I get:

```
Nick: acc1 Items each sum: 100
Total sale sum: 100 Items total: 1
Nick: acc2 Items each sum: 200
Total sale sum: 200 Items total: 1
Nick: acc3 Items each sum: 300
Total sale sum: 300 Items total: 1
Nick: acc4 Items each sum: 400
Total sale sum: 400 Items total: 1
Nick: acc5 Items each sum: 500
Total sale sum: 500 Items total: 1
```

I need:

```
Nick: acc1 Items each sum: 100
Nick: acc2 Items each sum: 200
Nick: acc3 Items each sum: 300
Nick: acc4 Items each sum: 400
Nick: acc5 Items each sum: 500
Total sale sum: 1500 Items total: 5
```

My problem is that the variable **sale_total_sum = 0** considers the amount only within one account, and not all together

Comment: As I see, you only print the second line one every call of the function - ie `get_on_sale()` is called multiple times. Is that correct?

Comment: You're resetting all the variables each time you call the function. They need to be global variables that you initialize once, and update in the function. And you have to call the function with `await`.

Comment: Or move the loop into the function.

Comment: @Saszem The function is asynchronous and is called once, multiple requests are sent in it

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, the notation of global functions helped solve the problem with counting, but I still don't understand how to output the final print with total counts without duplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically overwriting the variables as they are declared locally inside the function. To solve this:

Declare the following variables outside the function and make them global by using global keyword.

```
data = {}
sale_total_sum = 0
amount_total_items = 0

async def get_on_sale(session, dictt):
    global data = {}
    global sale_total_sum = 0
    global amount_total_items = 0
    ...
    ...
```

Remove the for loop at the end of the function and just print the below:

```
    ...
    ...
    print(f'Nick: {key} Items each sum: {each_sale_sum}')
```

At the end of the program, print the last line of the current function:

```
   ...
   ...
   print(f'Total sale sum: {sale_total_sum} Items total: {amount_total_items}')
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the script calculates the price of the items correctly, but I still can't display the last print correctly, I have duplicate lines. `Nick: acc1 Items each sum: 100
Total sale sum: 100 Items total: 1
Nick: acc2 Items each sum: 200
Total sale sum: 300 Items total: 2
Nick: acc3 Items each sum: 300
Total sale sum: 600 Items total: 3
Nick: acc4 Items each sum: 400
Total sale sum: 1000 Items total: 4
Nick: acc5 Items each sum: 500
Total sale sum: 1500 Items total: 5`

Comment: I tried to move the print in different ways but without success, maybe there is some way to wait for all requests to be completed?

Comment: I solved it by outputting print in main function

Comment: That's what I've said in my answer, print the last one at the end of the program!